# Untrack an object in Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

When querying an object with Entity Framework Core, it is kept in the local cache. If I change this object and later query it again, I get my modified object rather than a fresh version from the database.

How can I make EF Core forget about that single object and have it queried again from the database next time?

I need to make a local change to an object (blank out the password of the requesting user) so that it's no longer available for the casual access. This change must never be stored to the database! But when dealing with password management, I need a fresh copy of that object with all data present.

Comment: Have you tried `.AsNoTracking()`? Such as `context.Users.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Id == id)`

Comment: Not yet, but that helps. Thank you!